Question regarding projecticle in freefall disregarding air resistance
This question is regarding the following problem
A stone is thrown up from the top of a tower 20 m with a velocity of 24 m/s at an elevation of $30^\circ$ above the horizontal. Find the horizontal distance from the foot of the tower to the point at which the stone hits the ground. Take $g = 10m/s^2$
I solved the problem as follows,
When the stone is thrown up it goes to maximum height and again reaches the height of the tower in doing so it covers some horizontal distance which can be calculated using the following formula
$$R = \frac{u^2\sin(2\theta)}{g}$$
Using this formula to calculate the horizontal distance travelled by the stone before it reaches back to the height of the tower we get that the distance travelled is, 49.824 m
Next to find out the horizontal distance traveled by the stone while falling from the height of the tower we must first find the time the stone takes to cover this distance.
This time can be given by the following quadratic
$$-20 = 12t - 5t^2$$
Solving the above quadratic yeilds the time to be 3.532 seconds so the distance travelled in this time is the horizontal component of the velocity of the stone multiplied by 3.532 this comes out to be 73.32 m.
Hence the total horizontal distance traveled in this time is 73.32 + 49.824 which gives 123.148 m.
However the answer to the above question is given to be only 73.32 m why is that the case is the answer wrong or am i making any mistake.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

If you want to split the trajectory into two parts like this, then the second part of the trajectory will start with the projectile traveling downwards, not upwards.  You can show that for this portion of the motion, you'll have $v_{0y} = -12$ m/s, not +12 m/s.
Alternately, you can just ignore the range equation part of your solution, and ask how long it will take for the ball to go from being launched to hitting the ground (without splitting the trajectory into two parts.)  In this case, the initial upward velocity will be $v_{0y} = 12$ m/s, you'll end up solving the quadratic in your original solution to find the total time of flight, and the horizontal distance derived from that will be the total horizontal distance.

Doing so however does not change the roots of the quadratic doesn't it?

@koiboi  Try it and see!

The roots do change however the total horizontal distance comes out to be 73.31 m which again does not match with the answer

I realised that the answer to the question in the book is wrong thanks!

This equation: $y(t)= y_0 + v_0 t -1/2gt^2$ describes the complete vertical motion from the moment the stone is thrown of the tower $t=0$ to the moment the stone hits the ground. So solving: $y_0 + v_0 t -1/2gt^2 = 0$ will give you $20+12t-5t^2=0$ and gives $t=3.5$ s.
Using this time for the horzizontal movement results a distance in the x-direction of 73 m.
So it is not necessary to split your calculation into 2 parts.
